# How to layer div's on top of each other with relative positioning

Tags: html, css

I need to place two transparent div's on top of each other, and then move them vertically from each other based on a percent value using only CSS. This is what I would like it to look like if the percent value was 20%:

[image: example]

In this example the div's are 100x100px, and the parent div simply have 10px left and right padding that results in 20% difference in vertical position. The code looks like this:

```
<div class="parent" style="padding: 0 10px;">
    <div class="child left"></div>
    <div class="child right"></div>
</div>

.parent {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.child.left {
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

.child.right {
    right: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

However I don't actually know the size of the div's in my production version of the CSS, that's why I need to be able to separate them with relative percent values instead of pixels.

Here is a fiddle of the example, and one that fails:

http://jsfiddle.net/rva18302/

I can change the markup in any way, the only requirements is that the root-div resize itself dynamically to fit the child-divs, and that the child-divs keeps the same aspect ratio (square).

Answer (score 0):

It works, but it obviously works relative of your page, as percentage is a variable value and pixel is a fixed value. You cannot assume 10px as 10% and believe that it will work.

Taking your example, I have changed the percentage value and it works.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rva18302/1/)**

**Code change:**

`<div class="parent" style="padding: 0 1.5%;">`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that percent values is relative to the parent, I just provided it as a bad example :) Here is another, perhaps better, bad example: http://jsfiddle.net/rva18302/3/. The positioning of the children are now correct, but the requirement that the parent/root-div must take up all space from it's children fails instead.

Comment: @TheQ - For that, you need to keep the width to `auto` and make the div to have a `inline-block` attribute for it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/rva18302/4/

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't seem to work, see the red border. http://jsfiddle.net/rva18302/5/

Comment: I am using firefox and can see the border to occupy the full width. What browser are you looking at?

Comment: Yep, i just noticed the same in firefox, was using chrome initially. Hmm, that odd...

Comment: Yes looks like it works fine in firefox. Chrome might need changing values on other elements too.

Comment: Just tried on a standalone HTML and it works fine. No sure why it's not running on the fiddle. You can check the same. - @TheQ

Comment: Still can't get it to work in chrome, but you might have steared me in the right direction, I'll keep working with it :)

Comment: Sounds good. Make sure to accept/+1 the answer to ensure clarity for other users - @TheQ

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understood your question but if  you want to *'separate them with relative percent values instead of pixels'* and keep responsiveness to parent div you could set width as percentage and it should work!!

For ex.:

```
.child {
  width:90%;
 }
.parent {
  width:100%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/rva18302/7/)

Comment: Forgot to mention that the child div's need to remain the same size, 100x100px, or at the very least keep the same square aspect ratio.

Comment: Calc was interesting, haven't seen that before :) Seems to not have full support in all modern browsers though, android specifically. And I can't use 100px, since I don't know the size of the children where I'm trying to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to use pseudo elements for this?

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
div:after {
  opacity: 0.5;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Nice solution! I should learn to use pseudo elements more often :) However I can't use it, since it will overlap other content, see http://jsfiddle.net/9y25mxan/2/.

Comment: @TheQ: How about adding margins to the 'test' div? http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/9y25mxan/3/

Comment: Then I would have to know the width of it. I'm starting to think this problem can't be solved the way I want, I'll start looking for other solutions.